# How to NOT reuse a resource in PHP during socket-action?

Tags: php, sockets

We have the following setup:

- A server written in JAVA who accepts connections, gets data, calculates a result and sends it back. This is located one one machine.
- A client written in JAVA which connects, sends data and waits for the response of the server. These work from different machines as the server.
- A client written in PHP which should be able to do the same work as the JAVA-client. Works from different machines as the server too.

Anytime there are several JAVA-clients who contact the server and exchange data and responses. This works fine. Using just one PHP-client works as well.

The problem occurs when several PHP-clients are launched. They all use the same resource when fired from the same web-server. This results in the unpleasant situation that if you close one client because the work is done, the transmission to the other PHP-Clients will be terminated as well because the shared resource will be closed.

**What we need is a unique resource in PHP for every script-start so we can work and close it separately from all others. Is this possible?**

The network-connection from PHP-side will be started like this:

```
function network($host, $port) {
    if ( ($socket = @socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === FALSE ) {
        return -1;    
    } else {
        echo "Resource available? ".is_resource($socket)."<br />";
        if ( ($result = @socket_connect($socket, $host, $port)) === FALSE ) {
            return -2;
        }
        return $socket;
    }
}
```

The closing of the socket in PHP is simple:

```
socket_close($socket);
```

Comment: It looks like you are using solaris. You probably can do a simple REST call instead of using sockets.

Comment: It is an Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache/2.4.54. The JAVA-Server is the front-ent and the databases can not be "seen" from outside.

Comment: How do you launch the other PHP clients?

Comment: You have server A which is a JAVA-Server and a SQL-database. In the past only JAVA-Clients accessed the server. Now we have a webserver B for our customers. This webserver needs to send data in the same format like the JAVA-Clients to the JAVA-Server and the webserver has no access to the SQL-database. Asynchronous Customers activate the PHP-clients at different times when shopping or exchanging data with us.

Comment: I don't think the resources are shared. This will only happen at a fork. Try using `socket_set_nonblock($socket);` or the opposite after connecting.

Comment: At least PHP comes up with the info that the resource-number is the same. So I think they are shared. Nonblock does not wait for answer and runs into a timeout. Block works for one PHP-connection but sends a "reset by peer 104" to the second which is clear because the resource is blocked by blocking-operation. Is there no chance to ask in the socket-creation for a new resource?

Comment: I am using PHP 8.1. This returns a Socket instance instead of a resource. Maybe a PHP upgrade would solve your problem instantly?

Comment: That is an idea which may solve the troubles - I will try tomorrow and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Ok - we got it now. There were several issues at once: (1) The resource-id in PHP may be the same in different programs but it is not identical. (2) Our JAVA-server was doint earlier a lock so only one connection at a time was possible - someone changed it to global static and that started the fiasko as new connection were written over older ones (3) The runtime of PHP was too short so we ran into timeouts. Alltogether formed a strange picture which we were able to sort out now. Thanks for your help.